# alter table in db2cc for all databases

Tags: db2

Does anyone help me to find a way to ALTER the DB2 tables in DB2CC tool(for windows) for all the present and connect databases. I am new to this environment. (DB2 version 9.7)
We have multiple testing environment and due to one change there are few new columns of few already present DB2 Tables, either we go to each database and run ALTER query for that very table ( that is one long process giving we have around 50 odd databases) or can I do the same with just single script for all the  tables from all databases?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a script in shell to do that. However, your question is too ambiguous, the script could be something like the following (you need to translate that to CMD or PowerShell).

In bash (linux)

```
MYTABLE=mytable
MYCOLUMN="mycolumn integer"
for i in $(db2 list db directory | awk '/alias/ {print $4}') ; do
  db2 connect to $i
  db2 "alter table ${MYTABLE} add ${MYCOLUMN}"
done
```

This will add a column called mycolumn of type integer in tables called mytable of all databases calaloged in the current node/instance.

BTW, db2cc is too old and deprecated.